# Custom typed authorize attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Its been hard time customizing authorize attribute with typed constructor parameters as per requirement. Intent is to avoid magic string roles (viz. "allow:manager:readonly, deny:creator:readwrite").

**What I have:**

```
public class AuthorizationAttribute : BaseAuthorizationAttribute
{
    public AuthorizationAttribute(params string[] authorizations) : base(authorizations) { }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {       
        //I can't show BaseAuthorizationAttribute, what it does is, parse
        //supplied role strings([ALLOW/DENY:ROLE:SUBROLE]) separated by ':'
        //and add it to appropriate list DeniedRoles/AllowedRoles
        foreach (var denyRole in DeniedRoles)
        {
            if (Principal.HasAuthorization(denyRole.Role, denyRole.SubRole))
            {
                filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
                return;
            }
        }

        foreach (var allowRole in AllowedRoles)
        {
            if (Principal.HasAuthorization(allowRole.Role, allowRole.SubRole))
            {
                return;
            }
        }            
        filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
    }
}
```

Usage: `[Authorization("allow:manager:readonly", "deny:creator:readwrite")]`

It just works **GREAT**.

**What I want:** Instead of role strings, I want to use role/subrole enums, to consume this attribute safely.

What I tried:
I made 2 enums: AuthorizationEnum - having all roles, AccessTypesEnum - having subroles and [deny | allow] is just bool.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class TypedAuthorizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private AuthorizationEnum _authority { get; set; }
    private AccessTypesEnum _accessType { get; set; }
    private bool _allow { get; set; }
    public TypedAuthorizationAttribute(AuthorizationEnum authority, AccessTypesEnum accessType = AccessTypesEnum.ReadOnly, bool allow = true)
    {
        _authority = authority;
        _accessType = accessType;
        _allow = allow;
    }

    public override object TypeId { get { return this; } }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {
        var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as CorePrincipal;
        var hasAuthority = principal.HasAuthorization(_authority, _accessType);

        if (hasAuthority && _allow)
        {                
            return;
        }            
        filterContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        filterContext.Response.ReasonPhrase = _authority.ToString() +":"+ _accessType.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage: `[TypedAuthorization(AuthorizationEnum.AppealManager)]`

For single role, it works PERFECT. But for list of roles, its been nightmare for me. In fact, I want ORing of multiple roles:

Usage like: `[TypedAuthorization(AuthorizationEnum.AppealManager), TypedAuthorization(AuthorizationEnum.ManageAppeals)]` won't solve my problem, since i want "AppealManager" **or** "ManageAppeals" users accessible to applied entity.

Further, I unsuccessfully tried (Later I knew, spec has [limited valid attribute parameter types](https://github.com/ljw1004/csharpspec/blob/gh-pages/attributes.md#attribute-parameter-types)):

- Create tuple (Well, i found this data structure natural to my need)
  of individual role (role, subrole, allow)
- Send multiple role tuples on constructor parameter.

Attribute constructor:

```
public TypedAuthorizationAttribute(params Tuple<AuthorizationEnum, AccessTypesEnum, bool>[] authorities){}
```

Usage: `[TypedAuthorization(Tuple.Create(AuthorizationEnum.AppealManager, AccessTypesEnum.ReadWrite, true), Tuple.Create(AuthorizationEnum.ManageAppeals, AccessTypesEnum.ReadOnly, false)]`

Hope you guys understand my problem. I am stuck here, any workarounds to address this? Any suggestion will be  greatly appreciated.